# how to handle the pdf.js type with typescript

Tags: typescript, pdf.js

I am tried to use `pdf.js` to load pdf in react project, this is the initial `pdf.js` function look like:

```
const initPdf = async () => {
    // We import this here so that it's only loaded during client-side rendering.
            const pdfJS = await import('pdfjs-dist/build/pdf');
            pdfJS.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc =
                window.location.origin + '/pdf.worker.min.js';
            const pdf = await pdfJS.getDocument('example.pdf').promise;

            const page = await pdf.getPage(1);
            const viewport = page.getViewport({ scale: 1.5 });

            // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions.
            const canvas = canvasRef.current;
            const canvasContext = canvas.getContext('2d');
            canvas.height = viewport.height;
            canvas.width = viewport.width;

            // Render PDF page into canvas context.
            const renderContext = { canvasContext, viewport };
            page.render(renderContext);
  }
```

but the code `const pdfJS = await import('pdfjs-dist/build/pdf');` shows error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf'. '/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/source/reddwarf/frontend/texhub-web/node_modules/.pnpm/pdfjs-dist@3.9.179/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/pdfjs-dist` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'pdfjs-dist/build/pdf';`ts(7016)
```

I have already run the command to install the type of `pdf.js`:

```
npm i --save-dev @types/pdfjs-dist
```

still show this error. Am I missing something?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/pdfjs-dist says its deprecated. Do you have `pdfjs-dist` specifically installed already ?

Comment: yes, I have already installed the `pdfjs-dist` package.